# Magento 2: Widget/Block not working with caching enabled

Tags: magento-2.1

I have a widget which displays on the main page and the product category pages. Based on the user's selection in the widget the product results should filter. After that if we navigate to the category pages, the category filter should apply in addition to the widget selection.

Widget uses php COOKIE in the controller to retain the selection information.

**Problem:** When caching is disabled the widget works fine. But when caching is enabled it is not getting the selection information from main page to category pages or vice versa. I tried setting the block caching to false then it works partially. Do php cookies not work with caching in Magento? How to get it to work?